# C# - Intersection of Dictionary<int, SortedList<int, List<int>>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, dictionary, intersection

Consider the following code:

```
Dictionary<int, SortedList<int, List<int>>> ddl1 = new Dictionary<int, SortedList<int, List<int>>>();

ddl1.Add(1, new SortedList<int,List<int>>());
ddl1[1].Add(2, new List<int>());
ddl1[1][2].Add(3);
ddl1[1][2].Add(4);
ddl1[1][2].Add(5);

ddl1[1].Add(3, new List<int>());
ddl1[1][3].Add(3);
ddl1[1][3].Add(4);
ddl1[1][3].Add(5);


ddl1.Add(2, new SortedList<int, List<int>>());
ddl1[2].Add(2, new List<int>());
ddl1[2][2].Add(3);
ddl1[2][2].Add(4);
ddl1[2][2].Add(5);


Dictionary<int, SortedList<int, List<int>>> ddl2 = 
         new Dictionary<int, SortedList<int, List<int>>>();

ddl2.Add(1, new SortedList<int, List<int>>());

ddl2[1].Add(3, new List<int>());
ddl2[1][3].Add(3);
ddl2[1][3].Add(4);



ddl2.Add(2, new SortedList<int, List<int>>());
ddl2[2].Add(2, new List<int>());
ddl2[2][2].Add(3);
```

I am looking to get the intersection of these 2 complex dictionaries. The result should contain

```
1 { 3 {3,4} }
2 { 2 {3 } }
```

Can someone please help me with the LINQ query for this? Also, is it more efficient than the manual foreach and .contains method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Specify _intersection_.

Comment: @TimSchmelter According to the expected output, a deep intersection is meant

Comment: @Tim, By Intersection , i mean i want the elements that are common in all the 3 deep levels.

Comment: So where all is equal, the dictionary key, the sortedlist key and all of it's values?

Comment: @Tim yes. For example, if 2 dictionary have the same key but different value, then the intersection returns nothing. if they have the same key with the same value, then the intersection should return that key value pair.

I'm looking for somethign similar to my complex data structure. I am currently doing it manually using foreach/trygetvalue but I need better performance, so i was looking to use LINQ / PLINQ, and thats where I'm haiving trouble.

Comment: Shouldn't the first result be `1, {3 { 3, 4 }}`?

Comment: @Gert Arnold Oops my bad. Yes you are right, I've corrected it. Thanks for pointing it out

Comment: Curious to know: does PLINQ actually improve performance here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In short, better do it manually with foreach. I guess if you really want to do this through LINQ, you will have to create some custom `IEqualityComparer`s and this won't be less coding effort than just a manual foreach solution.

If you do it through LINQ, however, you may benefit from PLINQ. Apart from this, I don't see why the LINQ solution could be faster.

However, you can of course utilize `Intersect`. But remember that everytime you call ToDictionary as you suggested in the comments, you will create a new dictionary, which is time and memory consuming.

So this is the best solution I can think of, assuming you still need the `SortedList`. If not, replace by a usual dictionary.

```
var result = new Dictionary<int, SortedList<int, List<int>><();
foreach (var key1 in ddl1.Keys.Intersect(ddl2.Keys))
{
    var subList1 = ddl1[key1];
    var subList2 = ddl2[key1];
    var common1 = new SortedList<int, List<int>>();
    result.Add(key1, common1);
    foreach (var key2 in subList1.Keys.Intersect(subList2.Keys))
    {
        var subList1L2 = subList1[key2];
        var subList2L2 = subList2[key2];
        var common2 = subList1L2.Intersect(subList2L2).ToList();
        if (common2.Count > 0) common1.Add(key2, common2);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Georg. I dont think there is a need to create custom equality comparer. 

For a datastructure like Dictionary<int,List<int>>, i can do the intersection 2 levels using the code below:
" var result1 = Primary.Keys.Intersect(Secondary.Keys).ToDictionary(key => key, key => Primary[key].Intersect(Secondary[key]).ToList());"

I'm looking for similar code for the 3 levels.. Also, performance is a major factor for me, so I'm looking forward to acheive it through linq.

Comment: I can get significant improvement by using PLINQ right?

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to join the two dictionaries on the dictionary keys *and* the SortedList keys:

```
var q1 = from d1 in ddl1
         from sl1 in d1.Value
         select new { d1.Key, sl1 };
var q2 = from d2 in ddl2
         from sl2 in d2.Value
         select new { d2.Key, sl2 };

var q = from ds1 in q1
        join ds2 in q2
        on         new { key1 = ds1.Key, key2 = ds1.sl1.Key } 
            equals new { key1 = ds2.Key, key2 = ds2.sl2.Key } 
        select new
        { 
            key1 = ds1.Key,
            key2 = ds1.sl1.Key,
            Intersect = ds1.sl1.Value.Intersect(ds2.sl2.Value)
        };
```

The subqueries (`q1, q2`) flatten the dictionaries into a list of lists, so for the join the dictionary keys and the list keys can be combined.

Now you can benchmark whether parallelization does indeed increase performance, first by using `q2.AsParallel()` and then also `q1.AsParallel()`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
public static IDictionary<int, SortedList<int, List<int>>> Intersect(IDictionary<int, SortedList<int, List<int>>> x, IDictionary<int, SortedList<int, List<int>>> y) {
    IDictionary<int, SortedList<int, List<int>>> one = x.Keys.Intersect(y.Keys).ToDictionary(k => k, k => x[k]);
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, SortedList<int, List<int>>> kvp in one.ToList()) {
        one[kvp.Key] = new SortedList<int,List<int>>(kvp.Value.Keys.Intersect(y[kvp.Key].Keys).ToDictionary(k => k, k => y[kvp.Key][k]));
    }
    return one;
}
```